# How to add a custom Icon to an ElevatedButton.Icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to add a custom Icon to an ElevatedButton.Icon in Flutter

I imported my icons as a asset in the yaml but i dont know how to use them in Icon parameter

is there a way to use that or is there a completely different way than an ElevatedButton.Icon

Im thinking of using a container with a stack and place the my custom icon (.png img) on top of the elevated img that will be the second child of the stack

Comment: You might try this: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Image.asset('your_asset_path'),
                  label: Text('My elevated button'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to add icon with label you can use `ElevatedButton.Icon()` constructor like this:

```dart
 ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Image.asset("//imagePath"),
       label: Text("your label"),
     )
```

or if you want to add without any label or text you can directly user `ElevatedButton()`

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: () {},
       child: Image.asset("//image Path"),
  )
```

Comment: yes i did end up doing it that way haha thanks for the reply tho.